# "UUU" output in ModelSim on a specific output

Tags: vhdl, modelsim, quartus

Cordial greetings, your help has served me well. I have this situation:

I am making an ALU that adds, subtracts, multiplies (3X2 bits), and does logical operations. For this, I use the libraries "IEEE.std_logic_arith.all", "IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all" and "IEEE.numeric_std.all"; I did the multiplier separately, included it in the project, and "invoked" it.

The problem is in the multiplier. The code that I will present to you does compile, however, the RTL simulation (in ModelSim) gives the following answer:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gw1KG.png)

The "UUUUU" output is precisely when s es "010" that is, the multiplier output.

This is the code:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity alu is 
port(
       s: in std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);
       a: in std_logic_vector (4 downto 0);
       b: in std_logic_vector (4 downto 0);
       ci: in std_logic;
       co: out std_logic;
       r: out std_logic_vector (4 downto 0);
       f: out std_logic_vector (4 downto 0)
       );
end alu;

architecture comportamiento of alu is
component multiplicador
   port(
       a: in std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);
       b: in std_logic_vector (1 downto 0);
       ci: in std_logic;
       co: out std_logic;
       r: out std_logic_vector (4 downto 0)
       );
       end component;
   
signal ri: std_logic_vector (4 downto 0);
   
begin
   
       
   
   with s select
   
   f<=     a+b         when "000",
           a-b         when "001",
           ri          when "010",
           a or b      when "011",
           a xor b     when "100",
           a and b     when "101",
           "00000"     when others;
           

end comportamiento;
```

I am very grateful for your help.

Comment: Your code shows no entity instantiation, only a component declaration. Hence `ri` is connected to nothing, and initialises to `"UUUUU"`, exactly as you get in the simulation. You neeed to instantiate the multiplier.

Comment: wow yes, My fault. how do I invoke the multiplier output within the "with...s select... f<="?

Comment: @Tricky (No component instantiation, not even one with the reserved word entity.)

Comment: *how do I invoke the multiplier output within the "with...s select... f<="?* Associate signal `r1` as an actual for port 'r' in the port map of the component instantiation of multiplicador.. It's already an input to the f output multiplexer (the selected signal assignment).

Comment: I read something out there and assigned a signal to it since "r" is "out", the code: 
signal ri: std_logic_vector (4 downto 0);
  
begin
 
 r<= ri;
 
 
 with s select
 
 f<= a+b when "000",
   a-b when "001",
   ri when "010",
   a or b when "011",
   a xor b when "100",
   a and b when "101",
   "00000" when others;

I got the same output in models . I do not understand:

Comment: Modify your question to reflect your current question. Provide a [mcve].

Comment: I assigned a signal to `r` since `r` is _out_, however, I still get the same output

Comment: Provide a [mcve] in your question.

Comment: `r<= ri` and `f<=ri when "010"`